# CollectionView Cell as Delegate and DataSource of CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Up to this point i have been using ViewControllers as the dataSource and delegate for my collectionViews and i have been typically creating my data in an array inside viewDidLoad.  I then use this array in cellForItemAt to populate the collectionView.

Now i want to use a custom cell as the dataSource and delegate of another collectionView.  As this cell is set as the dataSource and delegate i can use functions like cellForItemAt, but I'm not really sure how to build my array that i use to populate the collectionView.

Whats the first function i can use inside a custom cell to run some background tasks and build an array?

Comment: You shouldn't run data retrieval background tasks inside the cell. You should already have the data and simply assign it to a property of the cell in your view controller's `cellForItemAt` (or worst case, initiate the load of the data in `cellForItemAt` but use some sort of caching so that you don't need to re-fetch the data if the cell is displayed again)

Comment: In custom cell class,use `init` or `awakefromnib` method if your loading the cell from nib. Also you can set the data in cellForItem method of the main class and then reload the innercollectionview which has custom cell.